# error using directory_entry in boost filesystem

Tags: boost, filesystems

I'm starting to use the Boost library in my C++ programs using Code Blocks on Ubuntu.

I encounter a problem while manipulating files, the following code returns a segmentation fault :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    boost::filesystem::path my_file("/home/malinou/workspace/grunbaum2/grunbaum/Bases/config.txt");
    cout << "my_file path : " << my_file.string() << endl;
    cout << "my_file exists : " << boost::filesystem::exists(my_file.string()) << endl;
    cout << "my_file path : " << my_file.string() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using gcc compiler with flags `-lboost_system` and `-lboost_filesystem`, and the console output is :

```
my_file path : /home/malinou/workspace/grunbaum2/grunbaum/Bases/config.txt
my_file exists : 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Process returned 139 (0x8B)   execution time : 0.093 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

Any idea why my_file seems to cause a problem after calling the `exists()` function?

(P.S: The problem is the same when I call the `is_regular_file()` function instead of the `exists()` one.)

Comment: sorry, can't reproduce. Your code works fine on my machine.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're actually using?

Comment: hint: if you compile with `-g` and then run your program using `gdb executable`... `run<enter>`, you should see exactly where things go wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is the code I'm actually using and it bugs me because this code is so simple I can't understand why it's going wrong :/

I already have the -g flag for debugging, but I don't understand your "gdb executable...run<enter>" command.

Comment: Start gdb with your executable: `gdb yourprog`. Then wait for all the stuff to be printed. You're then greeted by the gdb prompt; there, type `run` and hit the enter key

Answer (score 0):

To finally answer my question, it seemed to be a linking error due to the IDE I used. I created a new project with the same files, and it worked perfectly...weird

Anyway, thanks for everyones' help!